# Proving operations of a quotient ring are well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, quotient-group

I'm a little confused about a specific bit of reasoning in proving that the $\times$ operator is well-defined for a quotient ring. I looked up a proof and it omits, without any mention, the part I'm confused about.

We want to show that for a two-sided ideal $I$ of a ring $R$, for any $r, s \in  R$

$$ (r + I) \times (s + I) = (rs + I) $$

is a well-defined operation. Since this is an equivalence of sets, I first start off with showing that any $x$ in the left hand-side must be a member in the right hand side. That's straightforward, since for some $i_1, i_2 \in I$,

$$ x = (r + i_1) \times (s + i_2) = rs + i_1s + ri_2 + i_1i_2$$

$i_1s, ri_2, i_1i_2 \in I$ from our assumption of an ideal, as is their sum. So $x \in (rs + I) $ and  $(r + I) \times (s + I) \subseteq (rs + I)$.

How do we prove the reverse? That is, $(rs + I) \subseteq (r + I) \times (s + I)$. We'd want $x \in (rs + I) \implies x \in (r + I) \times (s + I)$. I'm assuming the ring doesn't necessarily have a unit element over $\times$. We'd have to show something like for $i_0 \in I$, $rs + i_0 = rs + i_1s + ri_2 + i_1i_2 $, finding some combination of $i_1, i_2$ to match any $r, s, i_0$.

I feel like I'm missing something since the proof in the text I have completely ignores this direction.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are misunderstanding, the product $(r + I)\times (s + I)$ is **not** defined as the set of products $\{ ab : a \in r + I, b \in s + I\}$. It is defined as the coset of $rs$, and showing well-definedness means showing that this coset does not depend on which elements of $r + I$ and $s + I$ are chosen. Thus one needs to show that if $r - r' \in I$ (which says $r + I = r' + I$) and $s - s' \in I$ ($s + I = s' + I$), then $rs - r's' \in I$ (that is, $rs + I = r's' + I$).

Comment: Thanks! I must have been confused by a line in my text for the analogous proof for quotient groups / normal subgroups. If you're curious, it's in a comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $(r+I)\times (s+I) = rs + I$ is not an equality of sets, it's a mapping rule for the corresponding equivalence classes. That it's not an equality of sets you can check by taking $R=\mathbb Z$, $I=(5)$, $r=2$ and $s=3$. Then $rs+I=6+(5)$ which as a set contains $1$, so if we were to write $1=(2+k_1\cdot5)(3+k_2\cdot5)$, where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are some integers, and expand, this eventually leads to $1=6+5(3k_1+2k_2+5k_1k_2)$, equivalently
$$3k_1+2k_2+5k_1k_2=-1 \iff k_1=-\frac{1+2k_2}{3+5k_2}$$
However the right-hand-side is never an integer when $k_2$ is an integer.

The notation $r+I$ denotes the coset represented by $r$. For a moment, let's change notation so that $[r]$ denotes the coset represented by $r$. Then $R$ is decomposed into a disjoint union of cosets $\cup_j[r_j]$ where $j$ ranges over some index set.

We now can define a function $\operatorname{prod}\colon R/I \times R/I\to R/I$ by $\operatorname{prod}([r_i],[r_j])=[r_i r_j]$. Now one has to verify that this function is well defined, that is no matter which representatives we choose for cosets $[r_i]$ and $[r_j]$, we get the coset $[r_i r_j]$ back after applying $\operatorname{prod}$.

To go back to the example $R=\mathbb Z$, $I=(5)$, $r=2$ and $s=3$, we have $\operatorname{prod}([2],[3])=[6]$ by definition. But now we also have $[-2]=[2]$, so $$[6]=\operatorname{prod}([2],[3])=\operatorname{prod}([-2],[3])=[-6],$$ by definition. But this isn't contradictory because $-6$ and $6$ represent the same coset, that is $[-6]=[6]$.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by a line in the analogous proof for quotient groups / normal subgroups. When showing that for a group $G$, normal subgroup $H$, $g, g' \in G, (gH)(g'H) = (gg'H)$ is well defined, the text states "Hence we must show that the set $gHg'H$, which consists of the products of all elements of the set $gH$ with all elements of the set $g'H$, is equal to the set $gg'H$". In this case, the set-of-products and set equality interpretation must work?

Comment: @karansag yes, in the multiplicative notation for groups we have $gg'h=(g\cdot 1)(g\cdot h)\in gHg'H$. However, rings are abelian groups together with multiplication, so this is also true for the group structure of a ring, but we have to switch notation from multiplicative to additive, so $(r+I)+(s+I)=(r+s) + I$ as sets is true for rings since $(r+s)+i=(r+0)+(s+i)\in (r+I)+(s+I)$.

Comment: That makes sense. My comment was more about the fact that, if I'm understanding correctly, you can interpret the group expressions as equality of sets (but NOT all the ring expressions, as you mention in your answer). So $gH g'H = \{ab: a \in gH, b \in g'H\}$ and $gH g'H = gg'H$ denotes a set equality.  Thanks again, great answer!

Comment: @karansag Yes, exactly, for the group structure it will always be an equality of sets because a subgroup always contains the group's identity, but for the other operation in the ring an ideal will contain the identity for the other operation if and only if it is the entire ring.